# legend of fmodel don't show a colour

Tags: r, statistics

this is my code:

`library(statisticalModeling)
 library(mosaicData)
  glm1<-glm(married=="Married"~ educ* sector*sex+age, data= CPS85, family="binomial")
fmodel(glm1, ~age+sex+sector+educ,data=CPS85, type="response", educ=c(10,16))`

but this is the result

[no_colours_legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73euE.jpg)

The legend don't show the colours!!!

Can we help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there is legend with colors but line types and size is too small to be visible within Rstudio plot window. If you zoom you will be able to see the legend. You can also add lines with following command :

```
fmodel(glm1, ~ age+sex+sector+educ, data=CPS85, type="response", educ=c(10,16)) +
    geom_line(aes(x=age, colour=sex))
```

Also have you noticed the error message? try

```
table(CPS85$sector, CPS85$sex)
summary(glm1)
```